# How to change the color of an icon when hovered over

Tags: css, colors, hover, icons

What code do I add to this to make an icon change color, or change to a different color icon image when hovered over with the mouse?

```
i.pk-social-links-icon.pk-icon.pk-icon-twitter {
    content: url(yourimageurl.png) !important;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have an SVG or a font based icon, you need to apply a filter (considering it's a true PNG and have no background).
I recommend you to use this [website](https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/) (It converts hex colors to filter style).

For the hover, you need to add the same style name with ":hover" at the end, and inside that, put the filter. (or anything visual you want it to do), in this case I putted a filter that makes this color #de0d0d (kind of red).

```
i.pk-social-links-icon.pk-icon.pk-icon-twitter {
    content: url(yourimageurl.png) !important;
    width: 100px;
}
i.pk-social-links-icon.pk-icon.pk-icon-twitter:hover {
    filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(17%) sepia(44%) saturate(6167%) hue-rotate(356deg) brightness(103%) contrast(98%);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. This kind of works, but it turns the whole thing red. So now it's just a red circle. How do I only turn the solid elements of the png a different colour?

Comment: I recommend to you, using svg or font based icons instead of solid, but sometimes we absolutely need to use png and it is understandable, I'm glad I helped you. Can you accept this answer as valid? Thanks!